# Import es5 javascript in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

i'm facing a big problem because of a lack of knowledge on Typescript :

I have a local package called "medium-editor-extensions" (in es5) that rely on third part dependancies and export a single function. This local package has a bundle.js generated with babel and browserify.

I try to import that package in my angular project so i declare the package in the package.json, but when i try to use it, the build fail because of :

```
ERROR in [default] /home/dev/javascript/project/my-project/src/app/directives/medium-editor.directive.ts:2:27
Cannot find module 'medium-editor-extensions'.
```

Here is how i use the package inside a directive :

```
import * as getEditor from "medium-editor-extensions";
```

I tryed to declare the typings for the package with this :

```
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
declare namespace Euronews {
    export interface getEditor {
        (el: ElementRef): any
    }
}

declare var getEditor: Euronews.getEditor;
declare module 'medium-editor-extensions' {
    export = getEditor
}
```

but it still fail because i'm mis-understanding something !!!

Thanks for any help

PS: here is the code exported in the medium-editor-extensions package :

```
export var getEditor = function getEditor(el) {
    var MediumEditorOptions = {
        toolbar: {
            buttons: ['bold', 'italic', 'anchor', 'orderedlist', 'unorderedlist', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'MediumBlockquoteExtension']
        },
        paste: {
            cleanPastedHTML: true
        },
        extensions: {
            'widgetextension': wysiwygExtension,
            'MediumBlockquoteExtension': blockquoteExtension
        }
    };

    var editor = new MediumEditor(el, MediumEditorOptions);

    marked.setOptions({
        pedantic: true
    });

    return editor;
}
```

Comment: Does `medium-editor-extensions` export anything? You can only import what the module exports.

Comment: It may help if you put up your _systemjs.config.js/webpack.config.js_, where you are including the module in your build...

Comment: @MihaiRăducanu i've added a part of the package to show what is exported

Comment: @P.Moloney i used angular-cli to build the project so i don't manage the webpack part except what is in the angular-cli.json file

Comment: does this work `module.exports.getEditor = function(el) {` in medium-editor-extensions?

Comment: no it doesn't work